# Multil-level conditional query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Consider that I have some posts with **category, subcategory, year, author, likes** etc.

```
ID      | CATEGORY      | SUBCATEGORY      | YEAR      | AUTHOR_ID      | LIKES
1       | A             | A1               | 2019      | 5              | 155
2       | A             | A5               | 2018      | 7              | 127
3       | B             | B1               | 2019      | 9              | 186
4       | D             | D3               | 2018      | 5              | 409
5       | C             | C2               | 2019      | 3              | 12
6       | B             | B1               | 2019      | 1              | 252
7       | B             | B4               | 2017      | 2              | 856
8       | C             | C1               | 2019      | 8              | 56
9       | A             | A2               | 2019      | 6              | 378
```

And in the search result, I need the get the result with exact parameters as the first priority.

For eg: if my search parameters are 
**CATEGORY = B, YEAR = 2019, LIKES > 100**
the results will be **ID 3, 6**

but in the second priority, I need to get data with combinations like
(**LIKES > 100** & **YEAR = 2019**) OR (**CATEGORY = B** & **LIKES > 100**) OR (**CATEGORY = B** & **YEAR = 2019**)
then the results will be **ID 1, 3, 6, 9, 7**

so the final results in order of priority will be **ID 3, 6, 1, 9, 7** like so.
I apologise for asking the question in this way, but any helps would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried

Comment: What if you have 4 search parameters, how should they combine? In groups of 2 or 3?

Comment: Then it should check for combinations with 3 parameters in the 2nd priority & 2 parameters in the 3rd priority.